# "You've been living here [for] too long"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, time

Is it correct to say "You've been living here for too long"?

Or is it better to drop the *for*? "You've been living here too long."

Is either preferrable over the other for some reason?

Comment: There are literally thousands of instances where prepositions can be either inserted or dropped with little or no change of meaning.

Comment: I would say "far too long" but you didn't ask that.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is fine. However, the sentence with *for* is better than the one without, because the former is more explicit than the latter.

At the end of the day, it is up to one's convenience to drop it or make it explicit.